# Add new points to existing Polygon in Shapely

Tags: python, shapely

How do I modify an existing Polygon? For a start, I'd like to add a Point to its exterior.

`poly = Polygon([(0, 0), (1, 1), (1, 0)])`

I was looking for something like this:

`poly.append_at(idx=3, Point(1, -1))`

But I cannot find any even similar methods for doing this.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It doesn't make sense to add or remove points from a `Polygon`'s exterior, because you'd want to recalculate `poly.area`, `poly.length`, etc. anyway. Instead, create a new `Polygon` instance from the old polygon's coordinates:

```
coords = poly.exterior.coords[:]
coords[1] = (2.0, 6.0) # coordinate to change

new_poly = Polygon(coords)
```

Note that this doesn't account for points in `poly.interior`.

Comment: @MikeToews: Re your comment below (may be deleted now) - I understand "immutable", but the very next statement in the documentation says "Their parent features are mutable in that they can be assigned new coordinate sequences.". That's what I was trying to do, assign a new sequence. For all I knew, an assignment of a new coord sequence **might** have triggered a re-calculation of area, centroid, etc. So I think the docs are a little misleading on that point.

Comment: @subnivean agreed, this blurb in the manual is not clear; see https://github.com/Toblerity/Shapely/issues/38