# How do you edit the coordinate of a polygon in Shapely?

Tags: python, computational-geometry, shapely

I have a shapely polygon: `polygon = Polygon([[0, 0], [1, 0], [1, 1], [0, 1]])`. Is it possible to edit the coordinate of one of the vertices without recreating a new polygon?

Comment: Why do you want to edit the vertices without creating a new polygon?
You would need to recalculate `polygon.area`, `polygon.length`, etc.

Comment: Ah thanks for that. Didn't realize those where fixed attributes

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Add new points to existing Polygon in Shapely](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14084290/add-new-points-to-existing-polygon-in-shapely)